# Exclude All International Traffic from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics, filtering

How do you exclude any & all traffic that isn't from USA & Canada in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, find the original answer posted [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13500/google-analytics-how-can-i-exclude-a-country-from-reports) by [John Conde](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde).